# HIbernate error - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "class" must match

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

below is hbm.xml

```
<class name="Location" table="LOCATION">
    <cache usage="read-only" />

    <id name="location_cd" column="LOCATION_CD" />

    <property name="location_type_cd" column="LOCATION_TYPE_CD"  not-null="true" />
    <property name="organization_id" column="ORGANIZATION_ID" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="census_ind" column="CENSUS_IND"/>



</class>
```

Could anyone help to understand why this error is coming?

Comment: Checked with  the following complete HBM , is this how the whole file looks like ?: <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-mapping><class name="Location" table="LOCATION">
    <cache usage="read-only" /> <id name="location_cd" column="LOCATION_CD" />
    <property name="location_type_cd" column="LOCATION_TYPE_CD"  not-null="true" /><property name="organization_id" column="ORGANIZATION_ID" not-null="true"/><property name="census_ind" column="CENSUS_IND"/></class></hibernate-mapping>

Comment: Did you checked fully qualified class name(class name with package name)

Answer (score 0):

I think the type of the columns are missing

you should change this like

```
<id name="id" column="LOCATION_CD" type="int"></id>

or

 <id name="location_cd" column="LOCATION_CD" type="int" />
```

Comment: I don't think declaring type in the mapping xml is mandatory. Hibernate's sensible defaults can automatically identify the mappings of properties to column.

Comment: Might be DTD specified in your DOCTYPE is not matching with the DTD existing in your project.